# Loading keras model on webcam video stream

Tags: keras, tensorflow.js

I have a keras model on depth perception, I want to load it using tensorflowjs, and apply it frame by frame on my webcam stream. Currently I am unable to capture my webcam video stream using HTML. How to do it?

Comment: I want to do load the model in a browser and the browser should open the webcam and stream it.

Comment: If you go on the github of tfjs, you have several examples doing just that

Answer (score 0):

you can use opencv and python to easily capture your video and make changes on it. for example you can use following code:

```
import cv2
import sys
from time import sleep

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
anterior = 0

while True:
    if not video_capture.isOpened():
        print('Unable to load camera.')
        sleep(5)
        pass

    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()


    # Display the resulting frameA
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes. but how to do the same on HTML page. I want to load it on a HTML page and then stream the webcam and represent my semantic segmentation.

Comment: Please share some of code you've tried here. .your question is general. But usually getUserMedia should work